# BatchUpdateException: Unknown column in where clause

Tags: java, mysql, sql

When writing to a mySQL db, i get the following error:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Unknown column 'ALFA' in 'where clause'
```

this is my java code:

```
public void pushWinner(String game, String teamW) throws SQLException{   
    String[] t1 = game.split("-");
    String statement = "update games set winner=(?) where team1 = "+t1[0]+" AND team2 = "+t1[1];
    try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(statement)) {                 
            pstmt.setString(1, teamW);
            pstmt.addBatch();
        pstmt.executeBatch();
        pstmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

I realy can't see what's wrong with the where clause...

**EDIT**

See my comment, forgot to mention what 'ALFA' is.

Data types for team1 and team2 are both VARCHAR(45).

Comment: Forgot this: 'ALFA' is the value of variable teamW

Comment: what are the data types of column Team1 and Team2 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this:** since  datatype of `column` `team1` and `team2` are `VARCHAR` so put `single quote` to compare it.

```
 queryString= "update games set winner=(?) where team1 = '"+t1[0]+"' AND team2 = '"+t1[1]+"'";
```

Comment: This is asking for trouble, works but open to attack. Just 'works' is not the only criteria to do something a certain way. See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Answer (score 0):

Your asking for trouble making sql like this. use a prepared statement with seperate parameters instead of inline param building. will stop issues like this and take care of parameter escaping. So use ? in the main sql to denoate location of a parm and use .setString(1, value); to set first (yes its 1 based). Or setInt(1, intValue) ... depending on data type. For date use java.sql.Timestamp - can convert a calendar to date and java.util.Date to sql timestamp OR new javax.time or joda. But dont use inline.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Why

1. ease of programming and
2. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Copied from the java tutorial :

```
    String updateString =
        "update " + dbName + ".COFFEES " +
        "set SALES = ? where COF_NAME = ?";

    String updateStatement =
        "update " + dbName + ".COFFEES " +
        "set TOTAL = TOTAL + ? " +
        "where COF_NAME = ?";

    try {
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        updateSales = con.prepareStatement(updateString);
        updateTotal = con.prepareStatement(updateStatement);

        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : salesForWeek.entrySet()) {
            updateSales.setInt(1, e.getValue().intValue());
            updateSales.setString(2, e.getKey());
            updateSales.executeUpdate();
            updateTotal.setInt(1, e.getValue().intValue());
            updateTotal.setString(2, e.getKey());
            updateTotal.executeUpdate();
            con.commit();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e ) {
        JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                System.err.print("Transaction is being rolled back");
                con.rollback();
            } catch(SQLException excep) {
                JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(excep);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (updateSales != null) {
            updateSales.close();
        }
        if (updateTotal != null) {
            updateTotal.close();
        }
        con.setAutoCommit(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Preparent statement with parametes as in the example. Do it that way your issue should go away, looks like not properly escapting the content. which is what parameters was made for. so malicious hackers cant manipulate the input to run other sql.

Answer (score 0):

If your datatype is string that you need `Single Quote` around your passed variable values

something like this...

```
String statement = "update games set winner=(?) where team1 = '"+t1[0]+"' AND team2 = ' "+ t1[1] + "'";
```